# DidSelectRow function is not called

Tags: swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to implement the didSelectRow function and perform a segue but when running the cells select and nothing happens.

I created a print statement that also doesn't run which proves that the function doesn't appear to be firing. Why would this be?

I have checked the identifier is correct and have researched these for a few hours going through many stack overflow threads but with little luck.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
    
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        let viewController = ListNameViewController()
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        var itemChoosen = 0
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            homeListsTableView.delegate = self
            homeListsTableView.dataSource = self
            viewController.loadList()
            
        }
        
        @IBOutlet weak var homeListsTableView: UITableView!
        
        @IBAction func templatesButton(_ sender: Any) {
            
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        }
        
        @IBAction func allListsButton(_ sender: Any) {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
            return viewController.listName.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            let result = viewController.listName[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = ("\(String(result.listName!))")
            return cell
            
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                context!.delete(viewController.listName[indexPath.row])
                viewController.listName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                viewController.saveList()
                homeListsTableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "items2", sender: self)
            print("selected")
        }
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(false)
            viewController.loadList()
            homeListsTableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(true)
            homeListsTableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }

ListNameViewController: 

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListNameViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var listName : [ListName] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        createButtonChange.isEnabled = false
        
        //Objective-C Line used to keep checking if the text field is vaild before enabling the submit button
        
        listNameValue.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textValidation), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var listNameValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationOption: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButtonChange: UIButton!
    
    @objc func textValidation() {
        //Text Field Validation check before button is enabled
        if listNameValue.text!.isEmpty {
            createButtonChange.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            createButtonChange.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    
    // Create a new List
    
    @IBAction func createButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let newList = ListName(context: context!)
        newList.listName = listNameValue.text
        saveList()
        self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
        viewWillAppear(false)
    }
    
    
    
    func saveList() {
        
        do {
          try context!.save()
        } catch {
          print("Error saving context \(error)")
      }
        
    }
    
    func loadList() {
          
          let request : NSFetchRequest<ListName> = ListName.fetchRequest()
          
          do{
            listName = try context!.fetch(request)
          } catch {
              print("Error loading categories \(error)")
          }
      }
    
    //Pass data to the HomeViewController
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       // let vc = segue.destination as! HomeViewController
        
    }
}
```

// commented out core data and just used a normal array for testing.

Comment: Are other UITableViewDataSource method called? Like `cellForRowAt`? What is `viewController`, is it totally different of your tableView ? Are you mixing the element?

Comment: ListNameViewController is used to add a new item to the tableView, and it's done this way so the homeViewController can access the data and display it from the listName array.

Comment: Could you check the value returned in numberOfRowsInSection ?

Comment: In a storyboard enviroment the default initializer `ListNameViewController()` will never return the instance in the storyboard. And it's bad practice anyway to locate the data source in another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add segue in your storyboard for the tableview ? In this case the didSelect is not call but the prepare(for segue) of the tableview controller is called.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, there is a segue in the storyboard which contains an identifier items2 which is the identifier used in the didSelect function using perform segue. If didSelect isn't called how do I get it to call from prepare for segue?

Comment: So after a lot of time, it seems that the didSelectRow function is being called but only on a long press, does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it - There was a rouge tap gesture recognizer on the page. Removed it and works on one click. I have seen that if you wish to keep the gesture just add this line of code at the top of the function:

```
 tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Took three days but I got there. Thanks for the help!